# apex:enhancedList component not displaying with Lightning enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, enhancedlist

I have a Visualforce page that uses an `apex:enhancedList` component on the page. When I have the Salesforce Classic look enabled, the list works properly (shown below):

[image: Functioning List View]

However, when I switch to the Lightning view, the list does not display anything, and all that is shown is the 'Loading...' message at the bottom. And when I try to switch List Views, there is a javascript error in the console:

[image: Broken List View]

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, what was your workaround, or did you have to stop using this component?

Comment: related: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_components_unsupported.htm

Comment: Let me test out some of the other components listed on that page to see if I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this component was not loading is because the ApexPage that was using the component did not have a high enough API Version Number. Once I changed the API Version to be 28.0, the component rendered correctly.